# how can i copy folders, subfolders and their files?

Tags: coldfusion

I have one folder called `misc` which contains few sub folders and each sub folders has sub sub folders and files in it and I want to copy the sub folders, sub sub folders and its files in a called `default` folder.

I have tried this getting empty folder. And also I am wondering why Coldfusion doesn't have copy attribute in cfdirectory tag.

```
<cfset CurrentDirectory=GetTemplatePath()>  
<cfset CurrentDirectory=ListDeleteAt(CurrentDirectory,ListLen(CurrentDirectory,"/\"),"/\")>  
<cfset NewDirectory="#CurrentDirectory#\default">  
<cfif NOT directoryExists(NewDirectory)>
<cfdirectory action="create" directory="#NewDirectory#">
</cfif>

<cfset strPath = ExpandPath("c:/wwwroot/test/misc") />
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="#strPath#" name="exDir">


<cfif exDir.type EQ 'File' >
   <cffile action="copy" source="#strPath#" destination="#NewDirectory#" mode="777">
</cfif>
<cfif exDir.type EQ 'Dir'>
   <cfdirectory action="create" directory="#NewDirectory#" mode="777">
</cfif>
<cfdump var = "#strPath#">
<cfdump var="#exDir#">
```

can anyone please let me know why I am getting empty folder ? any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked what all your variables hold, lest they don't hold what you think they do? Also instead of all that `listLen()` / `listDeleteAt()` stuff, you could probably use `getDirectoryFromPath()`, because it looks like that's what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: When i have tried without using listDeleteAt() and listLen() it gave me an error directory couldn't be created though I don't have same name directory in it.

Comment: If this is a one time requirement, why not do it manually?  If it's a recurring task why not look for a way to re-use the files as opposed to having to maintain multiple copies.

Comment: I think you need to troubleshoot your issues more coherently:"When i have tried without using listDeleteAt() and listLen() it gave me an error directory couldn't be created though I don't have same name directory in it" Did you bother to work out *why* it didn't create? It sounds like you're pretty much just coding at random here, and hoping for the best.

Comment: @DanBracuk - it is not one time requirement. I am keeping all those folders and files to be duplicated in Misc folder when there is need I will just put all folders and files from Misc to newly created folder. I know about copying files but don't know copying directories.

Comment: **ExpandPath("c:/wwwroot/test/misc")** is highly suspect here. ExpandPath accepts a relative path as its argument and returns values like the one you're attempting to pass in.

Comment: You also have a typo here: **<cfdirectory action="create" directory="#NewDirecotry#" mode="777">**

Comment: @waseem - Also, did you do what the first comment suggested? *...checked what all your variables hold, lest they don't hold what you think they do?*. That should be the first step in debugging. ie Verify the paths are what they should be. No point even running the rest of the code if the basic paths are wrong. Also, it would not hurt to include the actual (sanitized paths) values in your question as a point of reference.

Comment: @Leigh - I have checked out all the variables working fine and showing exact path i one i want and also when i list the source folder it shows all files and Dirs. still getting empty folder.

Comment: @waseem - What version are you using? CF9/10 support copy https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfdirectory. https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/DirectoryCopy

Comment: this attribute supports on CF 10 unfortunately I am using CF 9.0.1 and also I have tried it on Railo as well still it doesn't work.

Comment: @waseem - Yeah, I just tested it and you are right. In that case you will need to use the cflib udf Henry posted.

Comment: @Leigh - I have updated my railo now it supports copy attribute and it works fine on Railo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[directoryCopy()](http://cflib.org/index.cfm?event=page.udfbyid&udfid=1251) on cflib should do the job, or use [cfzip](http://www.bryantwebconsulting.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/3/12/Copy-a-Directory-Using-CFZIP)

Comment: DirectoryCopy supports on CF 10 and I have CF 9.0.1 :(

Comment: @Waseem, DirectoryCopy() on cflib works in CF9, it says it's not useful in CF10 'cause CF10 can do copy directory using built-in function

Comment: @waseem - Actually that link points to a *different* directoryCopy function. It is a udf from cflib.org that was written before CF9 came out.